# Create nested array data from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects that has information of nested data, and I want to convert the data to actual nested array data.
How can I convert this:

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1'},
  {id: 2, parent_id: null, name: 'test2'},
  {id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3'},
  {id: 4, parent_id: 2, name: 'test4'},
  {id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},
]
```

to this:

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1'},
  {
    id: 2, 
    parent_id: null, 
    name: 'test2',
    children: [
      {id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3'},
      {
        id: 4, 
        parent_id: 2, 
        name: 'test4',
        children: [
          {id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},
          {id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'}
        ]
      },
      {id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},
      {id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},
    ]
  },
  {id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},
]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create recursive function with `reduce` method for this.

```js
const data = [{id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1'},{id: 2, parent_id: null, name: 'test2'},{id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3'},{id: 4, parent_id: 2, name: 'test4'},{id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},{id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},{id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},{id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},{id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},{id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},]

function nest(data, parentId = null) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, e)
    if (parentId == e.parent_id) {
      let children = nest(data, e.id)
      if (children.length) obj.children = children
      r.push(obj)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(nest(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a single loop approach by using an object and the `id` and `parent_id` as key and collect the items/children to it.

The order is only important for the order in the children array.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1' }, { id: 2, parent_id: null, name: 'test2' }, { id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3' }, { id: 4, parent_id: 2, name: 'test4' }, { id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5' }, { id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5' }, { id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5' }, { id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5' }, { id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5' }, { id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5' }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[o.parent_id] = t[o.parent_id] || {};
            t[o.parent_id].children = t[o.parent_id].children || [];
            t[o.parent_id].children.push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Does this depend on the order? For example if `id:1` has a parent of `4`, it seems like it ends up in the wrong place.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, the order does not matter for parent children relations.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what it is. If I change the parent of item `id:1` from `null` to `4` it ends up in the wrong place.

Comment: please look below, children array comes first, but the item is in the right place.

Comment: I apologize — you are right! Just couldn't read my own output :(.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. One option if you want to keep linear time at the expense of some space it to make a lookup object based on `id`. Then you can loop through those values and push into either a parent object or the array:

```js
const data = [{id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1'},{id: 2, parent_id: null, name: 'test2'},{id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3'},{id: 4, parent_id: 2, name: 'test4'},{id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},{id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},{id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},{id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},{id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},{id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},]

let lookup = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.id] = item
  return obj
}, {})

let arr = Object.values(lookup).reduce((arr, val) =>{
  if (val.parent_id == null) arr.push(val)
  else (lookup[val.parent_id].children || ( lookup[val.parent_id].children = [])).push(val)
  
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this recursive approach

```js
const data = [{id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1'}, {id: 2, parent_id: null, name: 'test2'}, {id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3'}, {id: 4, parent_id: 2, name: 'test4'}, {id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'}, {id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'}, {id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'}, {id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'}, {id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'}, {id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'}];

const transform = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, elem) => {
     const children = data.filter(el => el.parent_id === elem.id),
           isPresent = findDeep(acc, elem);
     if(!isPresent && children.length)
       acc.push({...elem, children: transform(children)});
     else if(!isPresent)
       acc.push(elem);
     return acc;
  }, []);
}


const findDeep =(arr = [], elem) => (
   arr.some(el => (el.id === elem.id) || findDeep(el.children, elem))
);

console.log(transform(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, parent_id: null, name: 'test1'},
  {id: 2, parent_id: null, name: 'test2'},
  {id: 3, parent_id: 2, name: 'test3'},
  {id: 4, parent_id: 2, name: 'test4'},
  {id: 5, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 6, parent_id: 4, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 7, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 8, parent_id: 2, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 9, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},
  {id: 10, parent_id: null, name: 'test5'},
]

const output = data.filter(
  item => !item.parent_id
).map(
  rootItem => ({
    ...rootItem,
    children: data.filter(item => item.parent_id === rootItem.id),
  })
)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: What happened it id: 5?

Comment: Ah you're right there is more than one level of nesting, the best answer is probably the one using reduce.